# Presence of unordered_map determines whether copy-constructor or move constructor is used

Tags: c++, constructor, move, move-semantics

While extending some pre-existing code, I ran into a situation involving a few nested classes and move construction that produced very unexpected behavior. I was eventually able to produce two possible fixes, but I'm not confident I fully understand the problem to begin with.

Here's a somewhat minimal example, in which a class `Foo` contains a field of type `SubFoo` and a unique pointer, and has different copy- and move-constructors to reflect ownership of the unique pointer. Note that there are three macros which are undefined --- corresponding to the original, working state of the code (i.e. none of the asserts fail).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

//#define ADDMAP
//#define SUBFOO_MOVE
//#define FOO_MOVE_NONDEFAULT

class SubFoo {
public:
    SubFoo() {}
    SubFoo(const SubFoo& rhs) = default;
#ifdef SUBFOO_MOVE
    SubFoo(SubFoo&& rhs) noexcept = default;
#endif
private:
#ifdef ADDMAP
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t,uint32_t> _map;
#endif
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& name, uint32_t data)
    : _name(name),
      _data(std::make_unique<uint32_t>(std::move(data))),
      _sub()
    {       
    }

    Foo(const Foo& rhs)
    : _name(rhs._name),
      _data(nullptr),
      _sub(rhs._sub)
    {
        std::cout << "\tCopying object " << rhs._name << std::endl;
    }

#ifdef FOO_MOVE_NONDEFAULT
    Foo(Foo&& rhs) noexcept
     : _name(std::move(rhs._name)),
       _data(std::move(rhs._data)),
       _sub(std::move(rhs._sub))
    {
        std::cout << "\tMoving object " << rhs._name << std::endl;
    }
#else
    Foo(Foo&& rhs) noexcept = default;
#endif

    std::string _name;
    std::unique_ptr<uint32_t> _data;
    SubFoo _sub;
};

using namespace std;
int main(int,char**) {
    std::vector<Foo> vec;

    /* Add elements to vector so that it has to resize/reallocate */
    cout << "ADDING PHASE" << endl;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Adding object " << i << std::endl; 
        vec.emplace_back(std::to_string(i),i);
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "CHECKING DATA..." << endl;
    for (uint i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        const Foo& f = vec[i];
        assert(!(f._data.get() == nullptr || *f._data != i));
    }   
}
```

As mentioned above this is the working state of the code: as elements are added into the vector and it must be reallocated memory, the default move constructor is called rather than the copy constructor, as evidenced by the fact that "Copying object #" is never printed and the unique pointer fields remain valid.

However, after adding an unordered map field to `SubFoo` (which in my case wasn't completely empty, but only contained more basic types), the move constructor is no longer used when resizing/reallocating the vector. [Here is a coliru link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7d3d5e37adee9e1) where you can run this code, which has the `ADDMAP` macro enabled and results in failed assertions because the copy constructor is called during vector resize and the unique pointers become invalid.

I eventually found two solutions:

- Adding a default move constructor for `SubFoo`
- Using a non-default move constructor for `Foo` that looks exactly like what I would have imagined the default move constructor did.

You can try these out in coliru by uncommenting either of the 
`SUBFOO_MOVE` or `FOO_MOVE_NONDEFAULT` macros.

However, although I have some rough guesses (see postscripts), I mostly confused and don't really understand why the code was broken in the first place, nor why either of the fixes fixed it. Could someone provide a good explanation of what's going on here?

P.S. One thing I wonder, though I might be off track, is that if the presence of the unordered map in `SubFoo` somehow made move construction of `Foo` inviable, why doesn't the compiler warn that the `= default` move constructor is impossible?

P.P.S. Additionally, while in code shown here I've used "noexcept" move constructors wherever possible, I've had some compiler disagreement about whether this is possible. For example, clang warned me that for `Foo(Foo&& rhs) noexcept = default`, "error: exception specification of explicitly defaulted move constructor does not match the calculated one". Is this related to the above? Perhaps the move constructor used in vector resizing must be noexcept, and somehow mine wasn't really...

**EDIT REGARDING NOEXCEPT**
There's likely some compiler dependence here, but for the version of g++ used by coliru, the (default) move constructor for `SubFoo` does *not* need to have noexcept specified in order to fix the vector resizing issue (which is not the same thing as specifying `noexcept(false)`, which does not work):

[non-noexcept SubFoo move ctor works](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed13708b34e6dc01)

while the custom move constructor for `Foo` *must* be noexcept to fix things:

[non-noexcept Foo move ctor does not work](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88b41c152c16a853)

Comment: That's right, the unordered_map's [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) isn't noexcept, which explains the vectors reallocation behaviour. Whether defaulted special members can change the noexceptness is subject to various defects, I believe, so implementations may vary regarding which defect resolutions they implement.

Comment: @KerrekSB So, if I manually specify a noexcept SubFoo move ctor, the compiler might take my word for it as part of it's defect resolution? Also note my edit -- does the fact that I can leave off the noexcept specification and still fix the issue also up to compiler dependent implementation?

Comment: Vendors may add `noexcept` at their discretion. Regarding the defect, I *believe* (but am not sure) that this is the subject of wg21.link/cwg1778, as well as the recently adopted wg21.link/p1286.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard defect (in my opinion) that unordered map's move ctor is not noexcept.

So the defaulted move ctor being noexcept(false) or deleted by your attempted default noexcept(true) seems plausible.

Vector resizing requires a noexecept(true) move ctor, because it cannot sanely and efficiently recover from the 372nd element's move throwing; it can neither roll back nor keep going.  It would have to stop with a bunch of elements missing somehow.

Comment: `unordered_map`s move constructor can not be (unconditionally) noexcept because it has to move construct the hasher, the comparison functor, and the allocator - all three of which can be provided by the user.

Comment: Question: What do you mean by "[my] attempted default noexcept(true)" (I assume for SubFoo) -- is it somehow not a successful attempt?

Comment: FWIW, even a *non*-noexcept move ctor for SubFoo works (see here https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed13708b34e6dc01), while a *non* noexcept move ctor for Foo does noto (https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88b41c152c16a853)